# Sympy Lambdify - solving for unknown variable from two inequalities

Tags: python, sympy, lambdify

I have been successful solving for an unknown variable with solve()
Code here:

```
x = 1000  
y = Symbol('y')  
w = 2.84 * x > x + y, 1.7 * y > x + y  
solve(w)
```

Now I am trying to get the same result from a Pandas dataframe, unsuccessfully though.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.Series([2.84]),'B': pd.Series([1.7])})  
A = Symbol('A')  
B = Symbol('B')
C = 1000
y = Symbol('y')  
expr = A * C > C + y, B * y > C + y  
f = lambdify([A,B],expr, modules="sympy")
f(df['A'],df['B'])
```

I get the error - NameError: name 'y' is not defined
Which is weird because 'y' is what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0):

The `lambdify` function does not solve for anything, it only evaluates. To evaluate your `expr`, it needs to know A, B, and y. You have not provided y, hence the error.

If the goal is to determine y from A and B, you should first get a formula for y in terms of A and B,  presumably using the output of `solve`. Then lambdify that formula.

As it happens, `solve` can't solve multivariable inequalities. Even if it could, there would be a range of possible values of y, and `lambdify` needs something concrete to evaluate. To get somewhere with this, I replaced > with =, solved the equations, and returned the average of these (they are the upper and lower bounds for y, assuming B > 1 as in your example).

```
A = Symbol('A')  
B = Symbol('B')
C = 1000
y = Symbol('y')  
expr = (A * C > C + y, B * y > C + y)
upper = solve(expr[0].replace(Gt, Eq), y, dict=True)[0][y]
lower = solve(expr[1].replace(Gt, Eq), y, dict=True)[0][y]
f = lambdify((A, B), (upper+lower)/2)
```

Now f is a lambda with two arguments, which returns the midpoint of the interval of possible values of y.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.Series([2.84, 3.24]),'B': pd.Series([1.7, 2.12])}) 
f(df['A'], df['B'])
```

returns

```
0    1634.285714
1    1566.428571
dtype: float64
```